# Error when connecting to Heroku PG

Tags: postgres

When I connect to Heroku PG using pgAdmin III, I get the following error:

> 12:41:28 PM: Error: ERROR:  column "proisagg" does not exist
>       LINE 9:  WHERE proisagg = FALSE AND pronamespace = 16919084::oid
>                      ^
>       HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "pr.prolang".

What does this mean?  Is it a problem?